# How $_filter->getHtml() is generated?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I need to edit the result of `$_filter->getHtml()` function.

The `$_filter->getHtml()` returns an HTML content with `ul` and `li` combination for product attributes and I want to apply some modifications to this block.

What I want exactly is to convert some color names (e.g. red) to theirs hex equivalent (`FF0A0A`).

Do you have any idea on how to change the block contents?

Comment: What did you already tried to modify the block contents? Add the code with your attempts to the question.

Comment: I want to modify the color attribute , i need to change the color name to color code . for example red to FF0A0A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : 
The output of $_filter->getHtml() can be found in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml (filter items).